# python Find the most reported month

Tags: regex, string

I am trying to find out October(mentioned 2 times), I had the idea to use dictionary to solve this problem. However I struggled a lot to figure out how to find/separate the months, I was not able to use my solution for the 1st str values where there are some spaces. Can someone please suggest how can I modify that split section to cover - , and white space?

```
 import re
    #str="May-29-1990, Oct-18-1980 ,Sept-1-1980, Oct-2-1990"

    str="May-29-1990,Oct-18-1980,Sept-1-1980,Oct-2-1990"

    val=re.split(',',str)

    monthList=[]
    myDictionary={}

    #put the months in a list
    def sep_month():
        for item in val:
            if not item.isdigit():
                month,day,year=item.split("-")

            monthList.append(month)

#process the month list from above
    def count_month():
        for item in monthList:
            if item not in myDictionary.keys():
                myDictionary[item]=1
            else:
                myDictionary[item]=myDictionary.get(item)+1

        for k,v in myDictionary.items():
            if v==2:
                print(k)

    sep_month()
    count_month()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that regex is the best tool for this job, I would just use `strip()` along with `split()` to handle your whitespace issues and get a list of just the month abbreviations. Then you could create a dict with counts by month using the list method `count()`. For example:

```
dates = 'May-29-1990, Oct-18-1980 ,Sept-1-1980, Oct-2-1990'

months = [d.split('-')[0].strip() for d in dates.split(',')]
month_counts = {m: months.count(m) for m in set(months)}

print(month_counts)
# {'May': 1, 'Oct': 2, 'Sept': 1}
```

Or even better with `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

dates = 'May-29-1990, Oct-18-1980 ,Sept-1-1980, Oct-2-1990'

months = [d.split('-')[0].strip() for d in dates.split(',')]
month_counts = Counter(months)

print(month_counts)
# Counter({'Oct': 2, 'May': 1, 'Sept': 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import datetime
import calendar
from collections import Counter

datesString = "May-29-1990,Oct-18-1980,Sep-1-1980,Oct-2-1990"
datesListString = datesString.split(",")

datesList = []
for dateStr in datesListString:
    datesList.append(datetime.strptime(dateStr, '%b-%d-%Y'))

monthsOccurrencies = Counter((calendar.month_name[date.month] for date in datesList))

print(monthsOccurrencies)
# Counter({'October': 2, 'May': 1, 'September': 1})
```

Something to be aware in my solution with `%b` for the month is that `Sept` has changed to `Sep` to work (Month as locale’s abbreviated name). In this case you can either use fullname months (%B) or abbreviated name (%b). If you can not have the big string as with correct month name formatting, just replace the wrong ones ("Sept" for example with "Sep" and always work with date obj).

Comment: Thank You, I  did not think of using datetime option. I will experiment with this one.

Comment: I suggest to use the `datetime.strptime` instead of custom solution by looping the strings value and trimming or splitting the string as in future your data might change, and in that case you have to remove your custom implementation and create a new implementation. Meanwhile with the `datetime.strptime` function you just change your pattern format of the date and you can re-use the same code